# wordpress form validation using WP MVC

Tags: php, wordpress

I need to validate the form fields in wordpress WP MVC generated plugins.

I followed the tutorial of wpmvc but got no response.

Below code is used for validation:

```
/models/geozone.php

var $validate = array(
        'geozone_name' =>  array(
                'required' => true,
                'pattern' => '/^[A-Z]/',
                'message' => 'Please enter a capitalized name in the Geozone Name field!'
        ), 
        'state' => array(
            'rule' => 'numeric',
            'required' => true,
            'message' => 'you cannot leave this field empty!')
);
```

The record is added as usual.

Any idea to refine the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this myself.

This code works fine for 'edit' action. For validation of the fields using the above code we explicitly need to overwrite the 'create_or_save' function in the AdminController like this:

```
    if (empty($object['id'])) {
    ->  if ($this->model->create($this->params['data'])) {
            $id = $this->model->insert_id;
            $url = MvcRouter::admin_url(array('controller' => $this->name, 'action' => $this->_redirect_action, 'id' => $id));
            $this->flash('notice', 'Successfully created!');                
        }else{
            $this->flash('error', $this->model->validation_error_html);
        }   
        $this->redirect($url);
```

By adding the if condition shown above with the '->' arrow, it will validate the add form fields also.

Thanks.